# Unable to create indexed view in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing, view

I am unable to create clustered index on my view for a derived table.

Please help me to optimize my view where I can create an index as its my requirement to optimize. If indexing is not possible for my case please help me to write a faster view.

Here is my code:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAdded]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT t.id,
           t.Customer,
           t.Scanner,
           t.custType,
           FDGOrder,
           StatusID,
           TimeAdded,
           cntID,
           empID,
           effectChildren
    FROM dbo.smsFDGOrder t
    INNER JOIN dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus ON t.id = dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus.FDGOrder
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT smsFDGOrder.id,
               MAX(DISTINCT TimeAdded) AS MAX_TIME
        FROM dbo.smsFDGOrder AS smsFDGOrder
        INNER JOIN dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus ON smsFDGOrder.id = FDGOrder
        GROUP BY smsFDGOrder.id
    ) a ON a.id = t.id
        AND a.MAX_TIME = TimeAdded
```

I tried to add the index by this :

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAdded_ID
    ON dbo.VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAdded (id);
```

but got error:

> Msg 10109, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot create index on view "sharedmsdb-LIVE.dbo.VW_FGDOrderByMaxTimeAdded" because it references derived table "a" (defined by SELECT statement in FROM clause).
>   Consider removing the reference to the derived table or not indexing
>   the view.

Execution Plan for Devart Answer :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.5343.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementId="1" StatementText="CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX ixd ON dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus (FDGOrder, TimeAdded DESC)&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="CREATE INDEX" RetrievedFromCache="false" />
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="1" StatementEstRows="72653.9" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementSubTreeCost="10.5795" StatementText="&#xD;&#xA;SELECT t.id,&#xD;&#xA;       t.Customer,&#xD;&#xA;       t.Scanner,&#xD;&#xA;       t.custType,&#xD;&#xA;       s.FDGOrder,&#xD;&#xA;       s.StatusID,&#xD;&#xA;       s.TimeAdded,&#xD;&#xA;       s.cntID,&#xD;&#xA;       s.empID,&#xD;&#xA;       s.effectChildren&#xD;&#xA;FROM dbo.smsFDGOrder t&#xD;&#xA;JOIN dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus s ON t.id = s.FDGOrder&#xD;&#xA;JOIN (&#xD;&#xA;    SELECT FDGOrder, MAX(TimeAdded) AS MAX_TIME&#xD;&#xA;    FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus&#xD;&#xA;    GROUP BY FDGOrder&#xD;&#xA;) a ON a.FDGOrder = s.FDGOrder&#xD;&#xA;    AND a.MAX_TIME = TimeAdded" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x75C062BEC9148C5B" QueryPlanHash="0xF019E4D78D6C40" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan NonParallelPlanReason="NoParallelPlansInDesktopOrExpressEdition" CachedPlanSize="32" CompileTime="36" CompileCPU="36" CompileMemory="488">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="102297" EstimatedPagesCached="7864" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="49" EstimateCPU="0.317657" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="72653.9" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Merge Join" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="10.5795">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="ID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="Customer" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="Scanner" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="custType" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="StatusID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="cntID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="empID" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="effectChildren" />
              </OutputList>
              <Merge ManyToMany="false">
                <InnerSideJoinColumns>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                </InnerSideJoinColumns>
                <OuterSideJoinColumns>
                  <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="ID" />
                </OuterSideJoinColumns>
                <Residual>
                  <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[sharedmsdb-LIVE].[dbo].[smsFDGOrder].[ID] as [t].[ID]=[sharedmsdb-LIVE].[dbo].[smsFDGOrderStatus].[FDGOrder]">
                    <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="ID" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator>
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Compare>
                  </ScalarOperator>
                </Residual>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="23" EstimateCPU="0.0798894" EstimateIO="0.193495" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="72484" LogicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Clustered Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.273385" TableCardinality="72484">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="ID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="Customer" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="Scanner" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="custType" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="ID" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="Customer" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="Scanner" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" Column="custType" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrder]" Index="[PK_FDGOrder]" Alias="[t]" IndexKind="Clustered" />
                  </IndexScan>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="36" EstimateCPU="1.67094" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="72654.8" LogicalOp="Inner Join" NodeId="2" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Merge Join" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="9.9885">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="StatusID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="cntID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="empID" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="effectChildren" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <Merge ManyToMany="false">
                    <InnerSideJoinColumns>
                      <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                    </InnerSideJoinColumns>
                    <OuterSideJoinColumns>
                      <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                    </OuterSideJoinColumns>
                    <Residual>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[sharedmsdb-LIVE].[dbo].[smsFDGOrderStatus].[FDGOrder]=[sharedmsdb-LIVE].[dbo].[smsFDGOrderStatus].[FDGOrder] as [s].[FDGOrder] AND [Expr1007]=[sharedmsdb-LIVE].[dbo].[smsFDGOrderStatus].[TimeAdded] as [s].[TimeAdded]">
                        <Logical Operation="AND">
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                          <ScalarOperator>
                            <Compare CompareOp="EQ">
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                              <ScalarOperator>
                                <Identifier>
                                  <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                                </Identifier>
                              </ScalarOperator>
                            </Compare>
                          </ScalarOperator>
                        </Logical>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </Residual>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="19" EstimateCPU="0.445733" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="72440" LogicalOp="Aggregate" NodeId="3" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Stream Aggregate" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.57312">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                        <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <StreamAggregate>
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Column="Expr1007" />
                            <ScalarOperator ScalarString="MAX([sharedmsdb-LIVE].[dbo].[smsFDGOrderStatus].[TimeAdded])">
                              <Aggregate AggType="MAX" Distinct="false">
                                <ScalarOperator>
                                  <Identifier>
                                    <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                                  </Identifier>
                                </ScalarOperator>
                              </Aggregate>
                            </ScalarOperator>
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <GroupBy>
                          <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                        </GroupBy>
                        <RelOp AvgRowSize="19" EstimateCPU="0.750931" EstimateIO="1.37646" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="682522" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="2.12739" TableCardinality="682522">
                          <OutputList>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                          </OutputList>
                          <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                            <DefinedValues>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                              <DefinedValue>
                                <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                              </DefinedValue>
                            </DefinedValues>
                            <Object Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Index="[ixd]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                          </IndexScan>
                        </RelOp>
                      </StreamAggregate>
                    </RelOp>
                    <RelOp AvgRowSize="32" EstimateCPU="0.750931" EstimateIO="4.9935" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="682522" LogicalOp="Index Scan" NodeId="8" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Index Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="5.74443" TableCardinality="682522">
                      <OutputList>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="StatusID" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="cntID" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="empID" />
                        <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="effectChildren" />
                      </OutputList>
                      <IndexScan Ordered="true" ScanDirection="FORWARD" ForcedIndex="false" ForceSeek="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false" Storage="RowStore">
                        <DefinedValues>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="FDGOrder" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="StatusID" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="TimeAdded" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="cntID" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="empID" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                          <DefinedValue>
                            <ColumnReference Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Alias="[s]" Column="effectChildren" />
                          </DefinedValue>
                        </DefinedValues>
                        <Object Database="[sharedmsdb-LIVE]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[smsFDGOrderStatus]" Index="[_dta_index_smsFDGOrderStatus_5_1938105945__K2_K3_K1_K4_5_6_7_8]" Alias="[s]" IndexKind="NonClustered" />
                      </IndexScan>
                    </RelOp>
                  </Merge>
                </RelOp>
              </Merge>
            </RelOp>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: FYI : i am working with a huge data. so need to optimize .

Comment: What do you mean by **I am unable to create clustered index on my view**? Please post the error message. Also useage of `MAX()` is not allowed in Indexed Views

Comment: You are using `MAX` and subquery which are not supported in indexes views

Comment: Please provide execution plan for your query (`sqlplan`)

Comment: I have two tables one is order table other is status table. order table is referenced with status table . status table holds the TimeAdded filed. Actually we need to get the latest row for a order with the latest TimeAdded column, because there are multiple rows for a single order.

Comment: Again... without execution plan we could not to help you

Answer (score 0):

Variant #1:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix ON dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus (FDGOrder, TimeAdded DESC)
GO

SELECT t.id,
       t.Customer,
       t.Scanner,
       t.custType,
       s.FDGOrder,
       s.StatusID,
       s.TimeAdded,
       s.cntID,
       s.empID,
       s.effectChildren
FROM dbo.smsFDGOrder t
JOIN dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus s ON t.id = s.FDGOrder
JOIN (
    SELECT FDGOrder, MAX(TimeAdded) AS MAX_TIME
    FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus
    GROUP BY FDGOrder
) a ON a.FDGOrder = s.FDGOrder
    AND a.MAX_TIME = s.TimeAdded
```

Variant #2:

```
CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix2
    ON dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus(FDGOrder, TimeAdded DESC)
    INCLUDE (StatusID, cntID, empID, effectChildren)
GO

SELECT t.id,
       t.Customer,
       t.Scanner,
       t.custType,
       s.FDGOrder,
       s.StatusID,
       s.TimeAdded,
       s.cntID,
       s.empID,
       s.effectChildren
FROM dbo.smsFDGOrder t
JOIN (
    SELECT FDGOrder,
           StatusID,
           TimeAdded,
           cntID,
           empID,
           effectChildren,
           RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY FDGOrder ORDER BY TimeAdded DESC)
    FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus
) t ON t.id = s.FDGOrder
    AND t.RowNum = 1
```

Variant #3 ... the long way - aggregated table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus_Last', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus_Last
GO

SELECT FDGOrder, MAX(TimeAdded) AS MAX_TIME
INTO dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus_Last
FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus
GROUP BY FDGOrder
GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_l ON dbo.table_name (FDGOrder)
GO

CREATE /*UNIQUE*/ NONCLUSTERED INDEX ix2
    ON dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus(FDGOrder, TimeAdded DESC)
    INCLUDE (StatusID, cntID, empID, effectChildren)
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_ID
    ON dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus
    AFTER INSERT
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    ;WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *
        FROM dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus
        WHERE FDGOrder IN (SELECT i.FDGOrder FROM INSERTED i)     
    )
    MERGE cte t
    USING (
        SELECT FDGOrder, MAX(TimeAdded) AS MAX_TIME 
        FROM INSERTED
        GROUP BY FDGOrder 
    ) s ON s.ManufacturerName = t.ManufacturerString
    WHEN MATCHED AND (t.MAX_TIME != s.MAX_TIME)
    THEN
        UPDATE SET MAX_TIME = s.MAX_TIME
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET
    THEN
        INSERT (FDGOrder, MAX_TIME)
        VALUES (s.ManufacturerName, s.MAX_TIME);

END
GO

SELECT t.id,
       t.Customer,
       t.Scanner,
       t.custType,
       s.FDGOrder,
       s.StatusID,
       s.TimeAdded,
       s.cntID,
       s.empID,
       s.effectChildren
FROM dbo.smsFDGOrder t
JOIN dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus s ON t.id = s.FDGOrder
JOIN dbo.smsFDGOrderStatus_Last a ON a.FDGOrder = s.FDGOrder AND a.MAX_TIME = s.TimeAdded
```

Comment: Provide execution plan for this query... Thanks in advance

Comment: Thanks for your help . Please check your execution plan i have updated in the question above. u just one thing i had to modify in your code that is  : a.FDGOrder = s.FDGOrder instead of a.FDGOrder = t.FDGOrder.

Comment: Added variant #2... maybe it will be more convenient in your case

Comment: Both are same according to Execution time. i mean in case of varient 1

Comment: Variant 2 taking Few milliseconds extra.

Comment: In this case I suppose you don't need any indexes view? :)

Comment: may be ... but Thanks for your time. looks like almost same by 3 queries :(

Comment: Hm... so what about execution time. My and your queries are similar? Strangely...

Comment: Mine 241, Yours V1 : 221, Yours V2 : 802 in terms of milliseconds . :)

Another trial Results goes like this after adding non clustered  index:

mine 255 , Yours v1 : 261 :D Dont know why but strange !

Comment: Added variant #3 just for fun ;)